# How do I find a process and kill it in a single bash script

Tags: bash, shell

Currently I do the to following clear all processes running on port

```
lsof -i :10000
```

and I get

```
COMMAND     PID         USER   FD   TYPE     DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
Google    10427         user   60u  IPv4 0x162adea8      0t0  TCP localhost:52478->localhost:ndmp   (ESTABLISHED)
Google    10427         user  112u  IPv4 0x16289b98      0t0  TCP localhost:52483->localhost:ndmp (ESTABLISHED)
```

Then I kill it

```
kill 10427
```

I'm looking for a way to streamline the above process.
I'm guessing that the solution has to do with piping the output and killing it.
Something like (I think, here I assume that $1 is 10427).

```
lsof -i :10000 | kill $1
```

I've not done too much bash scripting so any help would be great.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you want something like

```
fuser -k -n tcp 10000
```

`lsof` soultion would be more like

```
lsof -i :10000|tail -n +2|awk '{print $2}'|xargs -r kill
```

Comment: Thanks, I got it working. I'm on osx, and xargs dosen't seem to have a -r option(I checked the man page [man](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/xargs.1.html)), should have mentioned that. The command works without the -r as well. Would you mind telling me what the -r does?

Comment: The `r` flag is for GNU xargs and means that the command should NOT be run if stdin is empty (i.e., do not run kill if awk doesn't output anything).

Comment: Thanks, @EmilVikström, and yes, stock osx xargs doesn't accept `-r`, though, if you have macports, you may use `gxargs` (most likely `findutils` port). Also osx `fuser` probably won't do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

I think Michaels answer is the nicest, but just for reference, you may do something like this as well:

```
PID=`lsof -i :10000 | awk 'NR == 2 {print $2}'`
kill $PID
```

Comment: err... that would try to kill `PID`. It's `tail`, not `head` what you wanted to do ;-)

Comment: oops, not `PID`, `COMMAND`. Because it's `$2`.

Comment: I know, I shouldn't log in to SO when I'm straight out of bed... :-/

Comment: Indeed, I'd rather stay in bed (not sure if it's widely supported attitude, tho:)).

Comment: thanks for the answer, it works fine as well. could you let me know what the NR == 2 does?

Comment: `NR == 2` means "match only the second line" (NR is the line number). I recommend you to learn some awk basics, since it is a really useful tool in Bash scripting.

Comment: Theoretically, there may be more than one process listening to the said port, provided they bind to different addresses, in which case it may be better to use `NR>1` or some such. And yes, that's smarter than using `tail` and then `awk` nonetheless ;-)

Comment: If matching multiple lines, make sure to pipe it through `sort` and `uniq` before killing.

Answer (score 1):

Or use this !

```
kill $(lsof -i :www | awk '{print $2}' | grep -v PID)
```